# First Order Logic - Writing a formula for values on the main diagonal of a 2d matrix

Tags: first-order-logic

I am trying to write a first order logic formula for the following: Let L = [C,=] be a vocabulary with C, a ternary relation symbol. Let K be the class of finite L-structures $\mathcal A$ in which A = [n] = [1,...n] and for each pair(a,b) $\in$ A, there is exactly one c ∈ A such that (a,b,c) $\in$
$C^{\mathcal A}$ (So C is like 2 dimensional matrix with indices and element all drawn from the same set A, where C(i,j,z) means the entry in $C_{i,j}$ is z.)

I want to write a formula with one free variable x, suich that in any structure $A$ $\in$ K, the formula defines the set of values that appear on the main diagonal of the matrix $C^{\mathcal A}$. I am not really sure how I could write this in first order logic. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $C(x,y,z)$ is true if $z$ is in the $(x,y)$th position of the matrix, and $z$ is on the diagonal whenever $z$ is the $(x,x)$th position for some $x$, we can see $z$ is on the diagonal if and only if $C(x,x,z)$ is true for some $x$.

Can you find a way to express this?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you for replying :) I came up with $∀_{x,y} ∃z ( x = y $ ^ $C_{x,y,z})$. Is this right?

Comment: Not quite! That would say that "for every x and y, I can find a z with C(x,y,z)". This tells you that every position in your matrix has something in it. Think about how z is on the diagonal if some x C(x,x,z) is true. Good luck ^_^

Comment: Second try: $∀_{y,z} ∃_x ( x = y → C_{x,y,z} $. I think what Im saying here is for every second index y and value z, there exists some first index x in which x and y are same [so (x,x)] and if that's the case, $C_{x,y,z} $ is true. It still doesn't work, doesnt it?

Comment: Closer! Here's another hint: you shouldn't need a $\forall$ quantifier. Remember, you want to say that z is on the diagonal, so you just need to find some position on the diagonal which proves that z is there. Keep trying ^_^

Comment: hmm okay, so since I am not talking about all indices, but just numbers on the main diagonal, I think I should use existential quantifier. Maybe $\exists x \exists y \exists z(x = y → C_{x,y,z})$ would work? There exists some numbers z at indices (x,y), and if x and y are same [ (1,1), (2,2) (3,3) ... (n,n)], there is a number z there. Am I almost there?

Comment: You're so close!!! The formula you have has no free variables, which means it has a true/false value by itself. You want to NOT quantify over z, so that you're left with a formula that takes z as an input, and RETURNS true or false.

Comment: Then the set of z which make your formula true will be exactly the z on the diagonal

Comment: yeah I forgot about the free variable, so after removing the quantifier over z, it would just be $$\exists x\exists y (x = y \rightarrow C_{x,y,z}) $$ Is this correct?

Comment: oh it asks for free variable to be x so maybe I should write  $$\exists i\exists j (x = y \rightarrow C_{i,j,x}) $$ instead.

Comment: You're SUPER close now. What is the $\rightarrow$ saying? "If i=j, then C(i,j,x)". Is that what we want to say? In particular, notice this is ALWAYS true (vacuously) if $i \neq j$. Keep at it, you're almost there ^_^

Comment: Thanks! $\exists i$ $C(i,i,x)$ would be fine?

Comment: Perfect!! You've got it ^_^